# Is the product of finitely many Noetherian rings itself noetherian?

Tags: ring-theory

If $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ are noetherian rings then is the product $A_1A_2...A_n$ noetherian.

I have searched this site for hints but only see questions related to the DIRECT product which is different.

Comment: What to you mean, $A_1\ldots A_n$? Is it the tensor product? Or $A_1 \times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_n$?

Comment: "product" very often means "direct product."  You'll have to explain how your context is different, if it is.

Comment: By my definition: If A,B are sub rings of a ring R then: $AB:=$ {$ \Sigma a_ib_i : a_i\in A, b_i \in B$}$

Comment: The set $A_1A_2\cdots A_n$ need not be a ring. For example, if $R=\mathbb{R}\langle x,y\rangle$ is the ring of polynomials in two noncommuting variables, $A_1=\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $A_2=\mathbb{R}[y]$, then $A_1A_2$ is not closed under products, as it contains $xy$ but not $xyxy$.

Comment: (I take, e.g., the set $A_1A_2$ to be the set of all finite sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$ with $x_i\in A_1$ and $y_i\in A_2$; but in any case, the meaning is unclear).

Comment: That’s exactly as defined in my uni notes

Comment: For **ideals** that works; the product of (two-sided) ideals is a two-sided ideal under that definition. But the product of subrings is not necessarily a subring.